# How to adress one or multiple audio streams that are in one RTPBIN?

Tags: java, gstreamer

I have a client sending 4 streams of audio with gstreamer like this:

```
gst-launch -v audiotestsrc freq=440 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! mulawenc ! rtppcmupay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.91 port=5000
```

the other 3 streams are the same, except the given frequency.

On the receiver side I have

```
gst-launch udpsrc caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=audio \" port=5000 ! rtppcmudepay ! mulawdec ! liveadder name=mix ! libvisual_lv_scope ! ffmpegcolorspace ! 'video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=25/1 ,width=1024 ,height=786' ! xvimagesink gstrtpbin ! mix.
```

which mixes the audio streams an displays them. So far so good.

What I need, is the possibility to filter out one or more of the audio streams from the RTPBIN on the receiver side. 
I believe this can be done with the SSRC and IP of each client, I have no idea how, though.

thx a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer myself.

GStreamers RTPBIN has a signal NEW_PAD_ADDED with the new pad as a parameter. You can subscribe to that signal and then hook up your next elements sink pad to the newly added source pad like this (java):

```
rtpbin.connect(new Element.PAD_ADDED() {            
@Override
    public void padAdded(Element element, Pad pad) {    

    PadLinkReturn linkOk;
    linkOk = pad.link(someElement.getStaticPad("sink"));
    System.out.println(linkOk);

    }
});
```

where someElement is the next Element in your pipe. LinkOk prints out the status of the link and why it has probably failed. check [this](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/googlecode/gstreamer-java/gstreamer-java/1.4/gstreamer-java-1.4-javadoc.jar!/org/gstreamer/PadLinkReturn.html) for reference

Comment: the problem identifying the client hosts persists, though. I have no idea, how to retrieve the CNAME from the rtpbin in java.